# Library resources with Robolectric 3 - JodaTime

Tags: android, jodatime, robolectric, android-testing

Getting an ResourceNotFoundException when using a library with Robolectic 3.0-rc3.  The resource is declared in build.gradle with compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.0'.   Specifically this is the Android port of Joda-Time.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f0501da
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.checkResName(ShadowResources.java:343)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.getResName(ShadowResources.java:333)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.openRawResource(ShadowResources.java:382)
at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java)
at net.danlew.android.joda.ResourceZoneInfoProvider.openResource(ResourceZoneInfoProvider.java:120)
at net.danlew.android.joda.ResourceZoneInfoProvider.<init>(ResourceZoneInfoProvider.java:39)
```

Application class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();    
    JodaTime.init(this);
}
```

My test class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,
    sdk = 21)
public class MyTest {

@Before
public void setup() {

}

@Test
public void myTest() {
//Test my stuff
}
```

}

Comment: I have the same issue, but tests are passing, the error gets just logged right?

Comment: No, test fail with the runtimeException at the JodaTime.init(this); line.

Comment: Sorry then. I use "net.danlew:android.joda:2.7.2" however I realized I am not doing this `init`. But I just tried `JodaTimeAndroid.init(activity)` and it worked in my test, maybe there is a difference between `JodaTimeAndroid` and `JodaTime`. Hope this can help you, good luck!

Comment: @Patrick did you have any luck with this. Experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I have not tried, but the latest release of Robolectric may resolve  the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to initialise the library in your tests, with the Robolectric runtime environment. So add this to your `setup()` methods.

```
JodaTimeAndroid.init(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
```

So your test would look something like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
public class MyApplicationTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        JodaTimeAndroid.init(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        //Test my stuff
        DateTime aDateTime = new DateTime();
        DateTime bDateTime = new DateTime(aDateTime);
        assertEquals(aDateTime, bDateTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have this exactly but still get the same issue with opening resources.

Comment: If you only run one test, instead of the entire suite, does it still happen? I've seen an issue before where because of a previous test that was run and hasn't done this right, it breaks other tests later